# How to replace a string in a table

Tags: sql, replace

i have a table like below

```
empid empname grade 
1      rr       A 
2      raju     B 
3      lokesh   A 
4      sathish  B
```

i want repalce the A by B and B by A in above table using single update statement can any one suggest a good answer in sql..

Comment: Which database you're working on?

Answer (score 2):

```
update your_table
set grade = case when grade = 'A' then 'B'
                 when grade = 'B' then 'A'
            end
where grade in ('A','B')
```

Comment: @Mr.Radical: Thanks for your concerns. But accepting an answer is totally up to the OP. Please don't ask users to accept something in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Update table
set grade = CASE  
               WHEN grade = 'A' THEN 'B' 
               WHEN grade = 'B' THEN 'A' 
            END 
     WHERE grade IN ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: This replaces only one case and not both at the same time as the OP wants.